Include sound in beamer presentation for multiple slides
I want to include sound in a beamer presentation and I want that sound to start on a certain slide and to last for multiple overlays or multiple slides. I tried to get that using media9 or multimedia (both of which should, accordung to the documentations, work). But in both cases (see MWEs below) the sound starts when it should start but it stop when item 2 is shown. How can I make the sound last for more than one slide (for one of the packages media9 or multimedia, I dont care for which)?
MWE for media9:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{1}
1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{2}
\includemedia[label=my_sound, width=1ex, height=1ex, transparent, activate=pageopen, deactivate=onclick, addresource=./Sounds/MITM.mp3,
flashvars={
source=./Sounds/MITM.mp3
&autoPlay=true
},]{}{APlayer.swf}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> 2
\item<3-> 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{3}
3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{4}
4
\end{frame}
\end{document}

MWE for multimedia: (here also the autostart option does not work and I have to start the sound manually and no sound at all is there without the option inlinesound)
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{1}
1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{2}
\sound[autostart, inlinesound, bitspersample=16, channels=2, encoding=Signed, samplingrate=48000]{A}{./Sounds/MITM.au}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> 2
\item<3-> 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{3}
3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{4}
4
\end{frame}
\end{document}

If this is important: I use Adobe Reader (the latest version) on Windows 11.

In case you know in advance how long each slide should be shown, you could create a video of the slides and combine this video with your sound.

During my presentation I want to be as flexible as possible, so that would not be a possible solution for me.

For this to work, the PDF viewer would need to be able to remote-control the media player plugin it is using. I am afraid this won't be possible anymore, since Adobe sent Flash and the Flashplayer plugin into retirement. The plugin was used in Acrobat Reader for media playback and could be controlled via JavaScript and ActionScript.

(An equivalent substitute has not been provided yet.)

Thanks for the comment. So it seems that what I want to do was once possible but is know not. I wonder (this is not really part of the question) why/how this seemingly great gap that Flash left is not filled yet

Just guessing but possibly there may be technical issues overcoming the security problems Flash had? Moreover, it was never very cross-platform friendly. Since lots of people nowadays use non-Adobe browsers, viewer support would doubtless be even more of a problem. But none of that says why. Only some possible whys which may not apply to the actual world at all ....

As far as I'm aware, none of the commonly-used PDF viewers currently support playing sound across multiple slides. However, it is fairly simple to make our own viewer that can support this.
Save the following to a file named viewer.html (or <anything>.html if you prefer):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="
            width=device-width,
            initial-scale=1,
            maximum-scale=1
        ">
        <style>
            /* Make the viewer take up the full screen */
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #viewer-container {
                overflow: clip;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            /* Center the page */
            .page {
                margin: 0 auto 0;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="module">
            import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf.mjs"
            import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf_viewer.mjs"
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf.worker.mjs"

            const bus = new pdfjsViewer.EventBus()
            const container = document.getElementById("viewer-container")

            const viewer = new pdfjsViewer.PDFSinglePageViewer({
                container,
                eventBus: bus,
                textLayerMode: 0,
                annotationMode: 0,
            })

            bus.on("pagechanging", () => {
                viewer.currentScaleValue = "page-fit"
            })

            const file_element = document.getElementById("file")

            async function open(event) {
                let file
                if (event instanceof window.DragEvent) {
                    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"
                    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
                } else if (event.target instanceof window.HTMLInputElement) {
                    file = event.target.files[0]
                }
                file_element.remove()

                const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(
                    await file.arrayBuffer()
                ).promise

                // Fix the background colours
                const BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "red"
                {
                    const page = await doc.getPage(1)
                    const PDFPageProxy = page.constructor.prototype
                    const render = PDFPageProxy.render
                    PDFPageProxy.render = function(params) {
                        params.background = BACKGROUND_COLOUR
                        return render.call(this, params)
                    }

                    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOUR
                }

                // Display the document
                viewer.setDocument(doc)

                // Play sounds
                const attatchments = await doc.getAttachments()

                let audio

                async function sound() {
                    viewer.currentScaleValue = "page-fit"

                    const page = await doc.getPage(viewer.currentPageNumber)
                    const annotations = await page.getAnnotations()

                    for (const annotation of annotations) {
                        const directive = annotation?.contentsObj?.str
                        if (!directive) continue

                        const [cmd, file] = directive.split(" ")

                        if (["play", "stop"].includes(cmd) && audio) {
                            audio.pause()
                            audio = null
                        }

                        if (cmd === "play") {
                            const blob = new Blob([attatchments[file].content])
                            audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
                            audio.play()
                        }
                    }
                }

                function move(direction) {
                    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
                        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
                    } else {
                        if (direction === "next") {
                            viewer.nextPage()
                        } else if (direction === "previous") {
                            viewer.previousPage()
                        }
                    }
                    sound()
                }

                document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
                    switch (event.key) {
                        case "ArrowRight":
                        case "ArrowDown":
                        case " ":
                        case "PageDown":
                        case "Enter":
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("next")
                            break
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                        case "ArrowUp":
                        case "PageUp":
                        case "Backspace":
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("previous")
                            break
                    }
                })

                document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    switch (event.button) {
                        case 0:
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("next")
                            break
                        case 2:
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("previous")
                            break
                    }
                })
            }

            file_element.addEventListener("change", open)
            document.addEventListener("drop", open)
            document.addEventListener("dragover", event => event.preventDefault())
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="application/pdf">
        <div id="viewer-container">
            <div id="viewer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Then, compile the following document using either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:
\documentclass{beamer}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Load required packages %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Needed to embed the audio files
\usepackage{embedfile}

%% Needed for \pdfannot to work with LuaTeX
\ifdefined\directlua
    \usepackage{luatex85}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Variable Declarations %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \seq_new:N \g__example_files_seq %% Store all used files
    \tl_new:N \l__example_lastfile_tl %% The most recent file loaded
    \tl_new:N \g__example_currentfile_tl %% The currently playing file

    % TeX Live <= 2022 compatibility
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_term:n { e }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
    \cs_if_exist:NF \str_mdfive_hash:n {
        \cs_new:Nn \str_mdfive_hash:n {
            \tex_mdfivesum:D { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }
        }
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Command Definitions %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %% Embeds a file if it isn't already embedded, and stores its attachment
    %% name in "\l__example_lastfile_tl".
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_add_file:n {
        \tl_set:Ne \l__example_lastfile_tl { \str_mdfive_hash:n { #1 } }

        \seq_if_in:NVF \g__example_files_seq \l__example_lastfile_tl {
            \seq_gput_right:NV \g__example_files_seq \l__example_lastfile_tl
            \embedfile [ filespec = \l__example_lastfile_tl ] { #1 }
        }
    }

    %% Writes to the PDF the given command and parameter.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_pdfcmd:nn {
        \pdfannot width 0pt~ height 0pt~ depth 0pt~ {%
            /Subtype~ /Text
            /Contents~ (#1~ #2)
            /F~ 1
        }
    }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__example_pdfcmd:nn { nV }

    %% Plays the given audio file.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_play:n {
        \__example_add_file:n { #1 }
        \tl_if_eq:NNF \g__example_currentfile_tl \l__example_lastfile_tl {
            \tl_gset:NV \g__example_currentfile_tl \l__example_lastfile_tl
            \__example_pdfcmd:nV { play } \l__example_lastfile_tl
        }
    }

    %% Stops the currently playing audio file.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_stop: {
        \__example_pdfcmd:nn { stop } { }
        \tl_gclear:N \g__example_currentfile_tl
    }

    %% Expose the commands publicly
    \cs_set_eq:NN \playaudio \__example_play:n
    \cs_set_eq:NN \stopaudio \__example_stop:
\ExplSyntaxOff


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% There are no audio files in $TEXMFDIST, so we need to lookup the
%% (system-dependent) path to a sample audio file.
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich~ --format=source~ bird.mp3 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \iow_term:e {
        \iow_newline:
        ``bird.mp3''~ path:~ \tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \iow_newline:
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title One}
        Body One
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Two}
        %% Replace this path with the path output to the terminal earlier
        \playaudio{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/source/latex/media9/files/bird.mp3}

        Body Two A
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2-> Body Two B
            \item<3-> Body Two C
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Three}
        \stopaudio
        Body Three
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Four}
        Body Four
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

Finally, open viewer.html in a web browser, click on “Browse”, and open up the PDF file that you compiled above. Clicking anywhere will make the presentation full screen, any of [Left Click, →, Page ↓, Space, Enter] will move ahead by one slide, and any of [←, Page ↑, Backspace] will move back by one slide.
How it works
On the TeX side, we add a sound file as a PDF “attachment”, then we place a play/stop command inside of a hidden PDF “annotation”.
On the HTML side, we import pdf.js to use as a base for our viewer, then we configure it to parse the annotations on each page and use them to decide when to play/stop any attached audio files.
The viewer is very barebones and not terribly robust, but it should generally be sufficient for a basic slide show. Adding new features and making it more robust is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Thanks for your answer. I did not have time to fully test and understand what you wrote but had to give the bounty, so I am giving the bounty for your answer (since it looks to be exactly what I want) and when I have more time I will look more closely into what you wrote.

In any case, +1 for "left as an exercise for the reader" ;)

I had now time to test the solution and I have two problems: 1. When compiling the tex-file I get several errors "Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}" and 2. When I want to open the file in the viewer I can browse and choose the file but nothing happens

@Martin I'm assuming that you're using an older TeX Live/MiKTeX version? If so, then the new edit should fix the errors with the TeX code. Regarding the HTML code, I've tested it again in Firefox and Chrome and it works for me, so I'm not too sure what's causing the problem. Can you try opening the page, pressing Ctrl-Shift-I to open the “Developer Tools”, select the “Console”, then open a PDF and see if it reports any errors?

Interesting approach, +1.

I am indeed using MiKTeX. With the new edit I get no errors. Now also the file opens and it does exactly what I want, thanks a lot.

After playing around with this solution a bit I have an additional small question: In my presentation I have a slide with blue background color. If I change the background color of the viewer to be also blue, I have a thin white stripe at the right border of the presentation. How can I get rid of this?

@Martin See the edit. (It's an ugly hack, but it seems to work alright)

That works, thanks again

I have a kind of follow-up question to this one (which I posted as a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718548/play-multiple-sound-files-simultaneously-in-beamer-presentation), if you have time to look at it ;)

This is not an answer but my resolution to the problem. I have faced essentially the problem described and after quite a bit of trying I concluded it's not really within the scope of PDF viewing currently.
Therefore I have switched from beamer-based PDF presentations to web-based presentations using frameworks like reveal.js. This has drawbacks in that typical js based latex rendering engines offer only a subset of latex, so the production time of slides has gone up.
The main drawback of the new approach is that it is more labor-intensive. I.e. if I do need certain latex renderings not supported by KaTex or similar latex based web renderers, I first render standard latex to a PNG file, embed as image on the slide where needed. The big gain is that adding audio content and video content has become easy, and adding interactive content (in form of javascript programs) is very doable but bespoke work. My work often includes algorithmic realizations hence it is nice to be able to show the work seamlessly within the presentation (no alt-tabbing out etc). Reveal.js has libraries that even allows markup and sketching over top of animated and interactive content. I am hoping that the main drawback of this approach will be overcome with time, leaving an option that offers the best of all worlds.

Welcome to tex.sx.
