Play multiple sound files simultaneously in beamer presentation
This can be seen as a follow-up on this question.
(How) Can one include multiple sound files in a beamer presentation that each can start on a certain slide and last for multiple slides (this has been answered in the above question) and such that mutiple files can play simultaneously (e.g. one background sound and other sound files in the foreground)?

How would you do this outside a presentation? Are you sending the files to different cards/devices?

A fairly simple extension of my earlier answer:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="
            width=device-width,
            initial-scale=1,
            maximum-scale=1
        ">
        <style>
            /* Make the viewer take up the full screen */
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #viewer-container {
                overflow: clip;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            /* Center the page */
            .page {
                margin: 0 auto 0;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="module">
            import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf.mjs"
            import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf_viewer.mjs"
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.1.392/pdf.worker.mjs"

            const bus = new pdfjsViewer.EventBus()
            const container = document.getElementById("viewer-container")

            const viewer = new pdfjsViewer.PDFSinglePageViewer({
                container,
                eventBus: bus,
                textLayerMode: 0,
                annotationMode: 0,
            })

            bus.on("pagechanging", () => {
                viewer.currentScaleValue = "page-fit"
            })

            const file_element = document.getElementById("file")

            async function open(event) {
                let file
                if (event instanceof window.DragEvent) {
                    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"
                    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
                } else if (event.target instanceof window.HTMLInputElement) {
                    file = event.target.files[0]
                }
                file_element.remove()

                const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(
                    await file.arrayBuffer()
                ).promise

                // Fix the background colours
                const BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "#bfbfff"
                {
                    const page = await doc.getPage(1)
                    const PDFPageProxy = page.constructor.prototype
                    const render = PDFPageProxy.render
                    PDFPageProxy.render = function(params) {
                        params.background = BACKGROUND_COLOUR
                        return render.call(this, params)
                    }

                    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOUR
                }

                // Display the document
                viewer.setDocument(doc)

                // Play sounds
                const attatchments = await doc.getAttachments()

                const audios = {}

                async function sound() {
                    viewer.currentScaleValue = "page-fit"

                    const page = await doc.getPage(viewer.currentPageNumber)
                    const annotations = await page.getAnnotations()

                    for (const annotation of annotations) {
                        const directive = annotation?.contentsObj?.str
                        if (!directive) continue

                        const [cmd, file] = directive.split(" ")

                        switch (cmd) {
                            case "play": {
                                if (!audios[file]) {
                                    const blob = new Blob([attatchments[file].content])
                                    const audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
                                    audio.play()
                                    audios[file] = audio
                                }
                                break
                            }
                            case "stop": {
                                console.log(audios[file])
                                audios[file]?.pause()
                                audios[file] = null
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                function move(direction) {
                    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
                        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
                    } else {
                        if (direction === "next") {
                            viewer.nextPage()
                        } else if (direction === "previous") {
                            viewer.previousPage()
                        }
                    }
                    sound()
                }

                document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
                    switch (event.key) {
                        case "ArrowRight":
                        case "ArrowDown":
                        case " ":
                        case "PageDown":
                        case "Enter":
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("next")
                            break
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                        case "ArrowUp":
                        case "PageUp":
                        case "Backspace":
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("previous")
                            break
                    }
                })

                document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    switch (event.button) {
                        case 0:
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("next")
                            break
                        case 2:
                            event.preventDefault()
                            move("previous")
                            break
                    }
                })
            }

            file_element.addEventListener("change", open)
            document.addEventListener("drop", open)
            document.addEventListener("dragover", event => event.preventDefault())
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="application/pdf">
        <div id="viewer-container">
            <div id="viewer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

\documentclass{beamer}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Load required packages %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Needed to embed the audio files
\usepackage{embedfile}

%% Needed for \pdfannot to work with LuaTeX
\ifdefined\directlua
    \usepackage{luatex85}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Variable Declarations %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \seq_new:N \g__example_files_seq %% Store all used files
    \tl_new:N \l__example_lastfile_tl %% The most recent file loaded

    % TeX Live <= 2022 compatibility
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_term:n { e }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
    \cs_if_exist:NF \str_mdfive_hash:n {
        \cs_new:Nn \str_mdfive_hash:n {
            \tex_mdfivesum:D { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }
        }
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Command Definitions %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %% Embeds a file if it isn't already embedded, and stores its attachment
    %% name in "\l__example_lastfile_tl".
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_add_file:n {
        \tl_set:Ne \l__example_lastfile_tl { \str_mdfive_hash:n { #1 } }

        \seq_if_in:NVF \g__example_files_seq \l__example_lastfile_tl {
            \seq_gput_right:NV \g__example_files_seq \l__example_lastfile_tl
            \embedfile [ filespec = \l__example_lastfile_tl ] { #1 }
        }
    }

    %% Writes to the PDF the given command and parameter.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_pdfcmd:nn {
        \pdfannot width 0pt~ height 0pt~ depth 0pt~ {%
            /Subtype~ /Text
            /Contents~ (#1~ #2)
            /F~ 1
        }
    }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \__example_pdfcmd:nn { nV }

    %% Plays the given audio file.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_play:n {
        \__example_add_file:n { #1 }
        \__example_pdfcmd:nV { play } \l__example_lastfile_tl
    }

    %% Stops the currently playing audio file.
    \cs_new_protected:Nn \__example_stop:n {
        \__example_add_file:n { #1 }
        \__example_pdfcmd:nV { stop } \l__example_lastfile_tl
    }

    %% Expose the commands publicly
    \cs_set_eq:NN \playaudio \__example_play:n
    \cs_set_eq:NN \stopaudio \__example_stop:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Demonstration %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!25}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title One}
        \playaudio{test-1.mp3}
        Body One
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Two}
        \playaudio{test-2.mp3}
        Body Two A
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2-> Body Two B
            \item<3-> Body Two C
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Three}
        \stopaudio{test-1.mp3} % Note that ``\stopaudio'' needs the filename now!
        Body Three
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title Four}
        \stopaudio{test-2.mp3}
        Body Four
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

Before, we saved the currently-playing Audio object in the audio variable; now, we save any playing Audio objects in the audios hashmap, indexed by the filename. The main thing to watch out for here is that \stopaudio takes the filename to stop playing as an argument, whereas before it took no arguments.
